# Facebook Connect for BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, facebook

I'm looking for a solution similar to the iPhone Facebook Connect (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) for the BlackBerry platform. Basically, I need my users to authenticate against Facebook from within a native BlackBerry application (so, not a Web based mobile application). Is there a library I could use, and if not, what will be the correct approach to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Options for BlackBerry are:

- Use [Facebook Platform for Mobile](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/web/)
- Use [REST API approach](http://www.baskoro.org/facebook-blackberry-sdk) provided by Eki Y. Baskoro
- Try to port [JavaFB](http://code.google.com/p/javafb/) from J2SE to J2ME

Comment: Coldice - thanks. While the SMS interaction API and the FB Connect for Mobile Web do not answer my needs, I think the option of porting the JavaFB would work (I found an even closer project - http://fbconnect-android.googlecode.com/ Android Facebook), I'll try that approach.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to go through Facebook Connect authentication within my BB app. After cracking my head for three days I realised that it is the URL that is the culprit!

Basically these are what you need (assuming you are developing for 4.5 platform):

1. Using Browser Field, do a POST to http://m.facebook.com/login.php (the mobile version of Facebook) passing all the necessary arguments as per the Desktop application counterparts (one challenge is to get the signature generation correct).
2. Once the User successfully grants access, capture the URL of the success screen. You will obtain your auth_token.
3. Do a POST to the REST server to obtain the session key and secret given the auth_token you obtain.
4. Save the returned session key and secret, persist it, and wholla! your app is up and running.

I am developing a custom LoginScreen and FacebookFacade object to incorporate the first three steps above, if anyone is ever interested to reuse my code. It'll be GPLed, I suppose ;)

Comment: Hiii...it will be very greatful if u can provide me with a glimpse of yuor code...my email id is niks_tek3@yahoo.com

Comment: One thing more i want to ask...how to capture the URL of the success screen in order to obtain auth_token...

Comment: Using BrowserContent you can capture the URL with getURL() and parse the response accordingly. I will post the complete code shortly as I am tidying it up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Afzal, I had a similar problem and I've found out that I actually had a problem with my connection string. You can look at the following link there is some explanation and code for creating the correct connection string 
http://www.localytics.com/blog/post/how-to-reliably-establish-a-network-connection-on-any-blackberry-device/

and just add the connection string to the FetchThread where it opens the connection:

connection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(absoluteUrl+getConnectionString());

Comment: Guy Ephraim,

As I have mentioned, all other links in the Facebook connect page works except login button WHEN entered correct email and password.

I am using ";inteface=wifi" in every URL. I have no idea whats wrong. 
Please help.

Afzal

Comment: OK I think now it works (I added connection string to FacebookFacade class as well). 
I see the screen with "Friends List" button but when I debug it, the application does not have a "secret" from facebook. It has "session_key" but no secret has been returned by facebook. The response I get is like:

"session_key":"XXXXXXXXXX-XXXX","uid":XXXXX,"expires":0,"base_domain":"ABC.com"

but no secret ! is it all right? what if I need a secret as well ? can I get that ?

Comment: Did it !
I added a parameter 
arguments.put("generate_session_secret", "true"); 
in getSession(String token) and removed session_secret from signature.
Thanks guys you all have been a GREAT help !!

Afzal